# How to separate either side of "=" and print only the left hand side operand?

Tags: python

Input is a file with `"="` in each line.
I want the output file to just have the left hand side of `"="`

eg. `"word = name"` should give only `"word"`.

Answer (score 5):

Like so?

```
with open('workfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split('=')[0])
```

Comment: I want to print it for all the lines in the file. Using content.split(' =') is not printing all the lines. What am I missing? I am new to python ..

Comment: What is content? All lines or one line?

Comment: You will have to use a `for` loop. The `for` loop goes over each line one-by-one and you can run the `split` on each line that way. See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements or https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: @marcus: You'd want to consider the whitespace around the `=` sign in the OP's string. Currently the output will be `"word "`, which is different to the required `"word"`